# SharePoint 2013 and Office Web Apps

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps

I am trying to get SharePoint 2013 Foundation to work with Office Web Apps, but it does not seem to be working.

I followed [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx) to get it setup.  I have it setup behind a reverse proxy (ISS ARR).

When I attempt to create a document in SharePoint, the default dialog comes up:

[image]

How do I go about debugging this?  I'm not really sure where to start -

## Update

This is the process that I followed:

## Topology

The setup involved two servers.

### Server I (Office Web Apps)

- IP: 192.168.1.13
- Name: OfficeServer
- Local: office.domain.local
- Public: office.domain.com

### Server II (SharePoint)

- IP: 192.168.1.6
- Name: ShareServer
- Local: portal.domain.local
- Public: portal.domain.com

There is an IIS ARR with a wildcard SSL certificate that sits between both of these servers and the internet.  This is used for SSL offloading.

## OWA Setup

1. Prepare OWA Server:

   Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Static-Content,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Security,Web-Filtering,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-App-Dev,Web-Net-Ext45,Web-Asp-Net45,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Includes,InkandHandwritingServices
2. Install Office Web Apps
3. Deploy Farm:

   Import-Module OfficeWebApps
    New-OfficeWebAppsFarm –InternalURL "http://office.domain.local" -ExternalURL "https://office.domain.com" -EditingEnabled:$true -SSLOffloaded

## SharePoint Setup

1. Create Binding

   New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName office.domain.com
    Set-SPWOPIZone –zone “external-https”
    $config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
    $config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $false
    $config.Update()

Comment: You might want to add all the steps you actually followed then providing link to MSDN article, as you might had missed something... anyway try ULS Viewer to find out what's going on behind the scenes when you click on add new document, http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Does it works for viewing documents ?

Comment: @MuhammadRaja - No - when I click on a document it opens in the desktop application -

Comment: William, that means web office apps are not working on your server, did you joined your WFE with office web app server using PS

Comment: @MuhammadRaja - See my update for details on my installation -

Comment: Can you also verify office web apps configuration on server I, e.g. type this in browser https://server.contoso.com/hosting/discovery  and tell me what's the result

Comment: @MuhammadRaja I have uploaded the XML configuration here: http://1drv.ms/1cLXtAR